# Looping this code to get new dataframe based on previous calculated dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df2 = df.copy()
    df2['avgTemp'] = df2['avgTemp'] * tempchange
    df2['year'] = df2['year'] + 20
    df_final = pd.concat([df,df2])

OUTPUT:
    Country avgTemp year
0   Afghanistan 14.481583   2012
0   Afghanistan 15.502164   2032
1   Africa  24.725917   2012
1   Africa  26.468460   2032
2   Albania 13.768250   2012
... ... ... ...
240 Zambia  21.697750   2012
241 Zimbabwe    23.038036   2032
241 Zimbabwe    21.521333   2012
242 Åland   6.063917    2012
242 Åland   6.491267    2032
```

So currently I'm trying to make a loop so I can then do the same calculations for "df_2" and return "df_3", and keep doing this until I have a certain amount of new dataframes that I can then concatinate together. Thank you for your help! :)

So end result should be like df_1, df_2, df_3 and so on. So I can then concat them together into one big dataset

Comment: What is df_3 supposed to be? The same logic as for df into df_2?

Comment: Yes correct, so doing exactly the same calculation as for when creating df2, but using df2 as a reference to create df3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create multiple dataframes in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635145/create-multiple-dataframes-in-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would use a loop to solve the issue. The `x` I'm passing in the function `range` represents the number of loops you wish to do:

```
lists_of_dfs = []
for i in range(x):
    df_aux = df.copy()
    df_aux['avgTemp'] = df['avgTemp'] * (tempchange ** i)
    df_aux['year'] = df['year'] + (20 * i)
    lists_of_dfs.append(df_aux)
```

Finally with the full the list of dataframes:

```
final_df = pd.concat(lists_of_dfs)
```

The only condition is that the variable `tempchange` has to be (1+%), it can't be only the % change, otherwise the formula will fail.

Comment: You're a saviour and you're amazing, many thanks! Only had to remove the brackets to pd.concat(lists_of_dfs).

Comment: It's true, we are already passing a list, no need for the brackets. Thanks!